# IsAssignableFrom in covariance and contravariance

Tags: c#, reflection, .net-4.0, covariance, contravariance

How can I detect if type `x` is assignable from type `y` not only through inheritance hierarchy but also through covariance and contravariance?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`IsAssignableFrom` does check covariance and contravariance, you don't need anything else:

```
// Covariance
typeof(IEnumerable<object>).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(IEnumerable<string>)).Dump(); // true
typeof(IEnumerable<string>).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(IEnumerable<object>)).Dump(); // false

// Contravariance
typeof(Action<string>).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(Action<object>)).Dump(); // true
typeof(Action<object>).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(Action<string>)).Dump(); // false
```

Comment: Thanks man, I didn't realize that it checks for covariance and contravariance. An article on Google seems to indicate otherwise.